# Type State<> has no method [Android Studio Error] Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm facing problem when I'm trying to get value from my state

In my ViewModel

```
val items = MutableStateFlow<MutableList<String>>(mutableListOf())
```

In @Composable screen

```
val items: MutableList<String> by viewModel.state.items.collectAsState().value
```

Here I'm getting error:

> Type 'MutableList' has no method
> 'getValue(Nothing?,KProperty<>)' and thus it cannot serve as a
> delegate

I tried to change val to var and add packages like below but stil the same error

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need `value` when you are reading it via `by` ;)

Comment: `val items by viewModel.items.collectAsState()` should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
val items: MutableList<String> by viewModel.state.items.collectAsState().value
```

with

```
val items: MutableList<String> by viewModel.state.items.collectAsState()
```

or with

```
val items: MutableList<String> = viewModel.state.items.collectAsState().value
```

When using `by` it gets you access to the `value` directly.